Migratory 1,4-insertion into M-H bonds
Wikipedia has provided valuable points, I am more interested in the insertion of alkenes into $\ce{M-H}$ bonds:

The reaction involves the alkene and the hydride ligands combining within the coordination sphere of a catalyst. In hydrogenation, the resulting alkyl ligand combines with a second hydride to give the alkane. Analogous reactions apply to the hydrogenation of alkynes: an alkenyl ligand combines with a hydride to eliminate an alkene.


Some brief context about migratory 1,2 insertions from ChemLibreTexts:

Like 1,1-insertions, 1,2-insertions generate a vacant site on the metal, which is usually filled by external ligand. For unsymmetrical alkenes, it’s important to think about site selectivity: which atom of the alkene will end up bound to metal, and which to the other ligand? To make predictions about site selectivity we can appeal to the classic picture of the M–X bond as $\ce{M+X–}$. Asymmetric, polarized π ligands contain one atom with excess partial charge; this atom hooks up with the complementary atom in the M–R bond during insertion. Resonance is our best friend here!


That means we cannot consider heavily polarized complexes containing carbonyl groups for conjugate addition. 
I found this site, Odd-numbered π Systems which provides an example for the conjugated diene ligand insertion between $\ce{M-H}$ bond:

Complexes containing conjugated dienes are also viable precursors to allyl complexes. Migratory insertion of a diene into the M–H bond is a nice route to methyl-substituted allyl complexes, for example. Interestingly, analogous insertions of fulvenes do not appear to lead to Cp complexes, but some funky reductive couplings that yield ansa-metallocenes are known. External electrophilic attack (e.g., protonation) and nucleophilic attack on coordinated dienes also result in allyl complexes. In essence, one double bond of the diene becomes a part of the allyl ligand in the product; the other is used as a “handle” to establish the key covalent bond to the allyl ligand.



I am getting a six membered transition state for the second example:

 
1,4 insertion should thus be possible. However, I could not find any website quoting this directly, so I am assuming that it doesn't happen. If it does happen though, please share any other source/ ligand which can undergo the same, perhaps apart from conjugated dienes.

Hello, I am unable to recognise the concerns behind the closing votes for this question. It would be helpful if someone pointed that out (not enough context/no research etc) and I shall edit my question. I am still longing for answers, thanks

What changes you made in your final edit? If your changes are concrete, then only make the edits. Otherwise, it will unnecessarily be bumped in the homepage.

@NilayGhosh I am utterly sorry, I just thought of fomatting the picture a bit, I would make sure to edit properly in the first run. I have rollbacked this edit
